# petalinux issue reset to logic on zynq

Tags: linux, logic, reset, vivado

I've been developing a system on a Zynq chip using Petalinux.  One thing that has remained a mystery to me is a means to issue a reset to the logic side of the chip from petalinux.  In Vivado, when a memory mapped peripheral is added, a processor reset module is automatically inserted, and the reset is connected to the FCLK_ARESETx_N pin.  Is there a way to drive this reset from user-space?  I can happily control a logic reset from a memory mapped module but I've been curious about this.

Answer (score 3):

There used to be a sysfs interface in [slcr.c](https://github.com/Xilinx/linux-xlnx/blob/master/arch/arm/mach-zynq/slcr.c) for exactly this purpose but it was removed in [this commit](https://github.com/Xilinx/linux-xlnx/commit/7a8f733eb1685d823b5e71eb4b332826cc53751e). The reason for removal was because "reset controls for peripherals should never be used, since device
drivers control the peripherals"...

At the time you could assert the FCLK_ARESETx_N signal by writing 1 to `/sys/class/xslcr_reset/fpgax_out/reset`.

If you still want to use the reset signals from userspace, you can talk to the SLCR registers manually using the `devmem` command (or `mmap`, etc.). For me, the appropriate register is at 0xf8000240. This comes from...

- SLCR base address from the .dts is 0xf8000000
- offset for FPGA resets from slcr.c is 0x240

the nth bit will control the nth reset signal. To reset on *all* lines from userspace, use:

```
devmem 0xf8000240 32 0xf #Raise reset
devmem 0xf8000240 32 0x0 #Lower reset
```

Hope this helps!